# Errors while using libgraph library for "graphics.h"

Tags: c++, bgi

I tried to use libgraph  library on ubuntu to use "graphics.h" for a sample program .
But while compiling i get these errors :

```
g++ graph.cpp -o graph -lgraph 

/tmp/ccD6rrqg.o: In function `main':
graph.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `initgraph'
graph.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `cleardevice'
graph.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `grgetch'
graph.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `closegraph'
/tmp/ccD6rrqg.o: In function `bresen(int, int, int, int)':
graph.cpp:(.text+0x1f9): undefined reference to `putpixel'
graph.cpp:(.text+0x206): undefined reference to `delay'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do I need to add any more linker flags ? This program works on windows so I think the program itself is right .

I managed to get it run but the window crashes giving :

process_responses: Assertion `(((long) (dpy->last_request_read) - (long) (dpy->request)) <= 0)' failed.
also can I resize the window  to full screen ?? thankx!

Comment: Does your graphics.h header have the relevant `extern "C" ...` boiler-plate ?

Comment: #include<iostream>

#include<math.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<graphics.h>
using namespace std; this is what I added at header .

Comment: yep  it does have the extren "C" in it

Answer (score 0):

The [installation instructions](http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/libgraph/) for libgraph seem a bit... *casual*.  Chances are the library should just be explicitly linked in:

```
g++ graph.cpp -o graph /path/to/libgraph.a
```

or wherever it was installed.

Another possibility to investigate what library g++ uses:

```
 g++ -print-file-name=graph
```

though on my system, it just echoes `graph`.

Comment: yea I managed to get it run by doing as above  but now the window crashes very quickly and says :process_responses: Assertion `(((long) (dpy->last_request_read) - (long) (dpy->request)) <= 0)' failed.